# Enable spell check for various languages in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spellcheck

I use Yosemite with Chrome version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit). When writing in a text area the spell checker correctly detects English and French, but does not detect Spanish, and so it marks as wrong correctly written Spanish words:

[image: img]

I don't know why it happens. English, French and Spanish are set in Chrome:

[image: img]

and also in the Mac preferences:

[image: img]

Is there any setting to have Chrome/MacOS detect Spanish like it does for French and English?

Comment: It must be the Chrome, since it works purfectly in FireFox "Que tal usted"

Comment: Just tested in Firefox, I have the exact same issue.

Comment: hmmm... if you right click on the misspelled word and select the Spanish it works or not ?

Comment: OS X Language and region settings don't have anything to do with spellcheck as far as I know. Nor do Chrome's Language settings.

Comment: Buscar: on Firefox it works now that I have installed the Spanish dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you that you need to install it, but it is simple to do. So are you happy :) if yes mark my answer as done.

Comment: Actually I need to have it working on Chrome, not on Firefox.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

I do not use Chrome (often) and Firefox is my favorite browser.

So I added Spanish to the Spell check and if I right click and select it it works just fine.

[image: Spanish]

One drawback is it applies to the whole text so I can not spell check just a single word.

**If you want to do that in Chrome:**

Under the Edit tab select the Spelling and Grammar-> Show

[image: spelling]

Now select Spanish

[image: Spanish]

Comment: He asked for Chrome, not Firefox

Comment: I recommend you delete the irrelevant Firefox stuff in your answer to a question about Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The place where you set spell check is System Preferences/Keyboard/Text/Spelling.  Go to the Setup item there and check the boxes for all three languages you want, and then set it to Automatic.  Automatic doesn't always work perfectly, however.  Below is the result I get with just boxes for English, French, and Spanish checked and set to Automatic.

[image]

Comment: Tom where is the Spelling you mentioned? I don't see it in System Preferences/Keyboard (http://monosnap.com/image/aiOtsmB25Tn51osTzGddaVnUCfuNwK) and no way to check boxes for languages.

Comment: It still does not work, I have several languages selected (http://monosnap.com/image/zQf8MUqBQ1bqmh3KC3S3914adOaVMg, http://monosnap.com/image/Ly2ziRmEYLt3xjrI9YzHx7a49YcJAV) and Spanish is still not detected, Spanish words are still underlined in red. Thanks for you help Tom.

Comment: thanks, I've unchecked all but English, French and Spanish and still have the same issue.

Comment: @Florent2  Strange that it works for me but not for you.  I notice your Chrome is not up to date (should be 152 at the end), but doubt that matters.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Apparently Chrome more or less uses the built-in spellchecking of MacOS, and you'll have to set it to automatic so it works for all languages.

Comment: @xji no it does not. Otherwise "it would just work" and the internet "would not be full with questions" like this. Chrome uses its own text widget ... and it even uses its own dictionary.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere Maybe things have changed (the answer is more than 4 years old and my comment is 2 years old). Software changes rapidly. There was certainly a time when this setup worked. Anyways I use Firefox instead of Chrome now.